# Separate search on the pip

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i need to create a pipe for search user .

but i have problem with pipe .

i have 3 field : `name` , `username` , `email` .

i want to search I want to search individually with `username` or `name` or `email` .

But the problem is that you have to fill all the fields for work pipe .

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'search'
})
export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: UserModel[],
    nameSearch?: string,
    emailSearch?: string,
    userNameSearch?: string): any {
    if (!value) return [];

    if (!nameSearch) return value;
    nameSearch = nameSearch.toLocaleLowerCase();
    value = [...value.filter(x => x.name.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(nameSearch))]

    if (!emailSearch) return value;
    emailSearch = emailSearch.toLocaleLowerCase();
    value = [...value.filter(x => x.email.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(emailSearch))]

    if (!userNameSearch) return value;
    userNameSearch = userNameSearch.toLocaleLowerCase();
    value = [...value.filter(x => x.userName.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(userNameSearch))]

    return value;
  }
```

**whats the problem ? how can i solve this problem??**

**[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fkjtnz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsearch.pipe.ts)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to filter by one of the 3 terms 'username', 'name' or 'email' use a pipe, that includes a filter name and a term to search for (I renamed your Pipe for better understanding). Additionally I used ngModelChange to set those two properties, therefor I use only one way binding for the ngModel & finally I did a little cleanup for the models of the input elements.

I forked your [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-15f6av).

EDIT: To use all models at the same time for filtering your list I modified your Pipe just a little bit.

```
transform(
      value: UserModel[],
      nameSearch: string,
      emailSearch: string,
      userNameSearch: string
    ): UserModel[] {

    if (!value) return [];

    if (nameSearch) {
      value = value.filter(x => x.name.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(nameSearch.toLocaleLowerCase()));
    }

    if (emailSearch) {
      value = value.filter(x => x.email.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(emailSearch.toLocaleLowerCase()));
    }

    if (userNameSearch) {
      value = value.filter(x => x.userName.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(userNameSearch.toLocaleLowerCase()));
    }

    return value;
  }
```

Comment: no man , its not my answer . Maybe I want to fill in the fields separately and maybe I want to fill in the fields completely

Comment: OK, I modified your [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-urhtpr) so it filters by the 3 models and I will modify my answer.